# Why is $\Sigma (-1)^{n+1}a_n $ where $a_n = 1/\sqrt n + (-1)^{n+1}/n$ is divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My approach: looking at the n-term (which goes to 0), it becomes obvious that root/ratio test will be useless. So my only hope is comparision test.

But in Rudin the two results on comparision test are as follow:

1)
$|a_n| \leq c_n$ and $\Sigma c_n$ converges impluies $\Sigma a_n$ converges

2)
$a_n, d_n \geq 0$ and $a_n \geq d_n$, then $\Sigma d_n$ diverges implies $\Sigma a_n$ diverges.

Now none of th above two results apply to my case because to prove divergence, I need to use (2) but (2) is only applicable for positive series. So how do I proceed further?

Answer (score 4):

If $\displaystyle\sum(-1)^{n+1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\sum\left((-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$ is convergent, as $\displaystyle\sum(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent, then so is the difference, $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{n}$, a contradiction.